# $A= SJS^{-1}$ Where $J$ is in Jordan Normal Form with One Eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If we have that $A= SJS^{-1}$ where $J$ is in Jordan Normal Form with one eigenvalue, and we subtract $\lambda$ from $A$, why can we say that $(SJS^{-1}-\lambda I)^n=(S(J-\lambda I)S^{-1})^n$?

Comment: If you mean $\lambda$ by scalar multiple of identity matrix, it can be rewritten as $(SJS^{-1}-S(\lambda I)S^{-1} )^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $A-\lambda I = S J S^{-1} - \lambda I = S J S^{-1} - \lambda S S^{-1} = S(J -\lambda I ) S^{-1}$. Taking powers of both sides gives the result you want.

You can say more. Since $A-\lambda I$ is nilpotent, you have $(A-\lambda I)^n = 0$.

Comment: I think you just answered this question here as well! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2736125/proving-displaystyle-eat-e-lambda-t-sum-k-0n-1-fractkka

Comment: As I get older I tend to repeat myself. As I get older I tend to repeat myself.

Answer (score 1):

The equality

$$(SJS^{-1}-\lambda I)^n=(S(J-\lambda I)S^{-1})^n$$

is true without any regard to the first part of your question.

Comment: Why? Via i707107's comment?

Comment: No, via the defined operations on matrices and their properties, for example: $$\lambda I=\lambda(SS^{-1})=S(\lambda I) S^{-1}$$ BTW, your post is lacking that I besides the $\;\lambda\;$ ...