# Proving $e^{AT} = e^{\lambda t} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{t^{k}}{k!}(A - \lambda I)^{k}$ -final step

Tags: matrices, jordan-normal-form, matrix-exponential

Suppose that the Jordan canonical form $J$ of a matrix $A$ is an $n \times n$ Jordan block of the form $$J = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots &  0 & 0 \\  0 &\lambda & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots &  0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \lambda & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & \lambda & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \lambda\end{pmatrix}$$

and I want to show that $\displaystyle e^{AT} = e^{\lambda t} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{t^{k}}{k!}(A - \lambda I)^{k}$.

So far, I have shown that

$$e^{At} = e^{(TJT^{-1})}t = e^{\lambda t} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{t^{k}N^{k}}{k!} = e^{\lambda t}\sum_{k=0}^{n-k} \frac{t^{k}(J-\lambda I)^{k}}{k!}$$

My question is, how do I finish this? I.e., how do I get $(A-\lambda I)^k$ out of $(J-\lambda I)^{k}$ in my summation?

Thank you for your time and patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$e^{tA} = e^{t(\lambda I + A-\lambda I)} = e^{t\lambda I} e^{t(A-\lambda I)} = e^{\lambda t}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k (A-\lambda I)^k}{k!} = e^{\lambda t} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{t^k (A-\lambda I)^k}{k!}$$

as $(A-\lambda I)^n = 0$

Comment: @JackyChong your calculation are not correct because $A = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 2 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{array}\right)$ and in this cas my truncation works

Comment: You are right. I made a mistake.

Comment: There’s an important condition which allows the second rewrite that should be made explicit: $\lambda I$ and $A-\lambda I$ commute.

Comment: Yes but this condition is obvious since $I$ is the identity matrix which commute with all matrices

Comment: @Youem the only problem with this solution is that I need to use $J$ somehow. How does it fit in with your solution?

Comment: Indeed, you are using $J$ implicitly to prove that $A-\lambda I$ is nilpotent. Because, $A-\lambda I$ is equivalent to $J-\lambda I$ which is nilpotent.

Comment: @Youem yes, people keep telling me that, but they don't explain how or what it means.

Comment: Do you know equivalence of matrices ?

Comment: @Youem you mean from row-reduction?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76036/discussion-between-youem-and-alannister).

Answer (score 2):

By direct calculation, we see that
\begin{align}
e^{tA} = \sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{t^kA^k}{k!} = \sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{t^k (TJT^{-1})^k}{k!} = \sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{t^k TJ^k T^{-1}}{k!}.
\end{align}
Like you said
\begin{align}
J = \lambda I+N
\end{align}
where $N$ is nilpotent, the we have that
\begin{align}
J^k = (\lambda I+N)^k = \sum^k_{m=0}\binom{k}{m}N^{k-m}\lambda^m
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{t^kTJ^kT^{-1}}{k!} =&\ T\left(\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{1}{k!}\sum^k_{m=0}\binom{k}{m}N^{k-m}\lambda^m\right)T^{-1} = T\left(\sum^\infty_{m=0}\lambda^m\sum^\infty_{k=m} \frac{1}{k!}\binom{k}{m}N^{k-m} \right)T^{-1}\\
=&\ T\left(\sum^\infty_{m=0}\frac{\lambda^m}{m!}\sum^\infty_{k=m}\frac{1}{(k-m)!}N^{k-m} \right)T^{-1} = T\left(\sum^\infty_{m=0}\frac{\lambda^m}{m!}\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{N^k}{k!}\right)T^{-1}\\
=&\  T\left(\sum^\infty_{m=0}\frac{\lambda^m}{m!}\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\frac{N^k}{k!}\right)T^{-1} = T\left(e^{\lambda t}\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\frac{(J-\lambda I)^k}{k!} \right)T^{-1} = e^{\lambda t}\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\frac{(A-\lambda I)^k}{k!}.
\end{align}